# Door lock for doors with borders

Tags: doors, lock

The door has a border which is about 1.5cm raised from the door. The door has a barrel slide lock however because of the raised border there is no place to put the latch. This is why I initially just made a hole in the border and the sliding piece  of the lock would just go into this hole.

**The sliding piece going into the hole**
[image]

The hole has now failed as a bit has broken off and therefore the sliding piece no longer catches in this hole. The door no longer locks.

What are my options in this situation? 
Is there any way to patch the hole so it locks again? 
If I was to re-install this and use a latch instead of the hole how would I go about raising the sliding piece to the same level (1.5cm) as the latch?

**This is essentially what the lock mechanism looks like , im sure this picture will be much clearer than any picture i take with a camera.**

[image: Lock mechanism]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've added your image to the question, but in truth it's pretty fuzzy and doesn't tell us much; you should add one or two clearer ones. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: show the picture to one of your friends and ask them to identify what they are seeing

Comment: Hi , apologies for the picture . I was trying to get a close up of how the bolt goes into the hole. I will add some more context in the original post.